# SSL Certificate Renewal Broke Payment Gateway - Modulus Mismatch

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have encountered a problem with my website's SSL certificate renewal, and it seems to have affected my payment gateway. Here's a brief overview of the issue:

Background:

I have a payment gateway integrated into my website.
It was functioning correctly until I recently renewed my SSL certificate.
After the renewal, I can no longer open the payment gateway window.

**Observations**:

When I compared the modulus value of the old SSL certificate with the private key, they match.
However, when I compared the modulus value of the new SSL certificate with the private key, they do not match.

**Question**:

Why would the modulus value of the new SSL certificate not match the private key?
Could this modulus mismatch be causing the issue with my payment gateway?
How can I resolve this problem and get my payment gateway working again?
Additional Details:

I am using Linux server.
I followed the standard renewal process, and I did not generate a new private key during the renewal.
The SSL certificate is from Digicert.
I have backups of the old certificate and private key.

Comment: `I followed the standard renewal process`. Really? What process is that? We don't know what process you are using to create the failed Certificate Signing Request (CSR). There is a lot of information here, but nearly all of the important and relevant information has been omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of words here, what you seem to be saying is:

- HTTPS site was working
- certificate renewed
- new certificate does not match existing key hence HTTPS no longer working

This should not happen. If you followed the method specified by Digicert, then they have failed. If you did not follow the steps specified by Digicert, they should be able to tell you what went wrong. Digicert have visibility of what data you sent them and what data they sent you. You are paying Digicert for support. You need to speak to Digicert.